# Figures in table and display text on top and side

Tags: tables, floats, subfloats, legend

I'm looking for some latex code to produce a figure similar to this one:

Additionally it would be great, if one could use any resolution for the displayed images (let's assume them to be all the same size) and make them fit smoothly into the page automatically.

[image]

It would be great if someone provided some example code.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/25077) Please give a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/25077).

Comment: Check out first for a possible solution. TeX.sx is not a client service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

With packages `makecell`, `rotating` and `\tabularx` it is simple:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}% Your documentclass
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell, rotating, tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
{
\settowidth\rotheadsize{Type 3}
      \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{r  C  C  C}
\rotcell{Type 1}    &   Name A\par\smallskip
                        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-a}   
                        &   Name B\par\smallskip
                            \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-b}
                               &   Name C\par\smallskip
                                    \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-c} \\
\rotcell{Type 2}    &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-a}
                        &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-b}
                               &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-c}  \\
\rotcell{Type 3}    &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-a}
                        &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-b}
                               &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-c}
    \end{tabularx}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a great piece of code working well.

Comment: The actual name of type 1, type 2, type 3 are of different length, e.g. elephant, mouse, monkey. If your code used, the names are not centered looking a bit awkward. 
Would you know any way to solve this?

Comment: with `\settowidth\rotheadsize{Type 3}` you set width of rotated cells. you need to consider the longest text or instead it use `\setlength\rotheadsize{<desired length>}` .